# Any way to get line numbers for git status

Tags: git

Is there any plugin/module for `command line git` that would display "line numbers" for `git status` and assign each file path to a number?
Something like this:

```
1. modified:   projectx/src/lib/config.cpp
2. modified:   projectx/modules/somefile.h
3. modified:   projectx/longfilename/subfile/file.x
```

Reason I'm asking for this, is, because it can get annoying to type the whole file path (even using tab for auto completion), especially when it's a really long file path.
Then using the number for anything that needs to be done with the file,
`git add 1.` `git checkout 2.` or something like that.
I'm not that familiar with `git` to know all tricks it can do, I'm just a basic user, but I think something like this would speed things up.

Comment: For `git add`, you can use `git add -i .` to interactive with files by pressing single numbers and letters. `tig` is a good command line tool that supports some shortcuts. For example, `tig status` allows you to select to stage/unstage a file by pressing some keys. For other commands, a GUI tool may save the day.

Comment: ty, I will check what `git add -i` has to offer in this regard.

Comment: @ElpieKay Is `-i` the same as `—patch`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Not exactly. `-p` or `--patch` implies `-i` and it's a shortcut to `patch` of the `-i` menu.

Answer (score 1):

In some terminals (Git Bash among others) you can double-click any string* (here, the long file path, but it could be a branch name or anything else) and it will be selected and copied.

After that you just have to right-click to paste it where your cursor is. Very convenient when available.

* *(very common scenario : when doing an "add", typically you just did a "status" before that and have a display of modified files)*

Comment: True it does work that way, on linux can also just use middle mouse button to paste, but I would like to speed it up even more, not to have to move my hands from keyboard. In case I have more edited files, I always check the `diff` first, so have to do it for each file. On linux it's easy to apply last file with `Alt + .` but only after you pasted it beforehand.

Comment: @light01 In which cases do you have to repeatedly type long lists of long file paths? Maybe there's something else in the process that could be done better?

Comment: In this current case, I'm changing the project structure, it includes a lot of file paths changing and editing the files that use them to the new path. I could use `git add .` to add all if I needed to, but I prefer checking one by one to make sure I don't push anything that's not complete.